# How to Install ONE Operating System on Computer with TWO Hard Drives - NOT Dual-Boot

Tags: boot, mount, xubuntu, 16.04

I have a computer with two hard drives, one small, the other large.

I wish to install Xubuntu onto this computer with the operating system itself on the smaller hard drive and all of my data stored onto the larger drive. I would want the computer to operate 'seamlessly,' in other words, to have both drives mount together and to be able to go from one drive to the other just as though the computer had only one drive.

Is there anyone here who knows how to do that? I would need the mount points for the drives as well as the ability to create links to the data (on the large hard drive) within the Home page stored on the OS (small) drive.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Install the `/` in smaller drive, and `home` in larger drive.

Comment: @dattutbrus can you move this to an answer please.

Comment: Is system UEFI or BIOS. Either way if not also installing Windows I suggest gpt. It just is if gpt Windows only boots in UEFI, Ubuntu will work with gpt for BIOS or UEFI. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DiskSpace and if drive may ever be moved to a newer UEFI system include ESP - efi system partition now. http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu If you want /mnt/data on large drive instead of /home or in addition to /home: Splitting home directory discussion and details:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1811198

Answer (score 1):

Simple **BUT THIS IS ONLY FOR LEGACY BOOT MODE**

1. While installing, select the `Something else` option or something like that (**WARNING!** *The picture is to demonstrate. Select Something else, not in the picture*)

[image: Something else]

2. Let's do some maths.

---

- First, call your amount of ram *X*, small drive is *A* and large drive is *B*.
- Your swap should be in A with a space of *2X*.
- Your system, which is `ext3` or `ext4` should be mounted as / in drive A with a space of *A-2X*.
- Finally, your Home folders should be created as `ext4`, mounted
  as /home in drive B at a space of *B*.

---

Now just do the installation like you would do.

Comment: Anyway If you are in UEFI mode, you can just make an additional `/boot` partition in `ext4` with about 256MB-512MB and a Reserved BIOS one.